# open&close php tags on each line, within arrays, functions

Tags: php, tags

I collaborate with a web-programmer on a php project based in kirby cms, and he wants to open and close every line as such:

```
<main>
  <?php /*php code here/* ?>
    <?php /*more php here*/ ?>
 ...
```

Trying to follow this style, I found some errors in my code. The first is that it seems I canNOT do this in the middle of an array as such:

```
BAD CODE

<?php $oo = array( ?>
<?php  'h' => 100, ?>
<?php  'v' => 100, ?>
<?php ); ?>
```

but I can do it in the middle of a foreach loop as such:

```
<?php foreach ($p as $subp): ?>
  <div id='<?= $subp->title() ?>'>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Are there any other cases such as array in which I canNOT do this?

/edit

According to the answer, there can only be tag-breaks within 'foreach', 'while', or 'if' blocks.

How about a 'foreach', 'while' or 'if' within a function? is that 'legal'?:

```
<?php
function myFunction($arg){
  if($arg === 'this'): ?>
    <?= '<p>yep</p>' ?>
  <?php else: ?>
    <?= '<p>nop</p>' ?>
  <?php endif;
};
?>
```

And how about nesting if within foreach within function?:

```
<?php
function myFunction($arr){
  foreach($arr as $val): ?>
    <p><?= $val ?> <p>
    <?php if($val === 'this'): ?>
      <?= '<p>yep</p>' ?>
    <?php else: ?>
      <?= '<p>nop</p>' ?>
    <?php endif;
  endforeach;  
};
?>
```

edit/

Thank you

Comment: Seems strange that each line is opened and closed but it's a very interesting question. +1 and followed.

Comment: It affects the output, as you will have a **LOT** of linebreaks in the resulting html, and functions like `header` will not work.

Comment: Basically, if you're in the middle of a statement, you can't break out of it. If you're in the middle of a control structure, you most likely can. However, it doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: @AlexBlex I don't believe opening and closing php tags echos linebreaks

Comment: @BrandonFlynn-NB of course it does everything between the closing php tag and the next opening php tag is HTML and in this case includes at least one new line cahracter

Comment: Your PHP developer is a novice and thinks PHP works similar to HTML in which you must have open/close tags for each element.

Comment: what is with all the hate going on here, this is a help community and we should encourage questions that are not easy to google yourself. This I would argue falls in that category. We all started somewhere ...

Comment: @VictorRadu agree! The community seems to have changed since I needed it as a novice 6 years ago. A lot of users seem to be arrogant and/or pretentious, having forgotten what it was like to be beginners. Thank you for taking the time to answer his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot "break out of php" mid statement. wline defining an array for example you cannot close the php tags. The only time when you can "break out" of php is between opening and closing a loop or an if/else statement. This actualy does not break the statement as `<?php foreach: ?>` is a complete statement whereas `<?php foreach{ ?>` is not. Here some examples of what you can do:

```
<?php if($this!=$that): ?>
{something}
<?php endif ?>

<?php foreach($things as $thing): ?>
{something}
<?php endforeach ?>

<?php $while($this): ?>
{something}
<?php endwhile ?>
```

I think you get the message. you must have complete statements within php tags, without interruptions.

P.S. Also avoid using the shorthand `<?` instead of `<?php` at all cost, moving your project to a different hosting or an upgrade of your hosting might break your project as per default short tags are not activated. `<?= ?>` shorthand is safe as this is unaffected by the setting for newer php versions.

P.P.S Do not listen to the guy who wants php in one line, this will make your code hard to read and maintain. Stand strong and write beautiful code :)

UPDATE: (after the update on the question from @Jaume Mal)
I did not mean the examples in my answer as exclusive but as examples of statements that are complete vs statements that are incomplete. (I also forgot to mention closing php tags mid fuction, wich also work but I despise and woudl strongly advise against.) So for example `<?php function foo(){` is a complete statement of starting a function but (as the other cases with loops etc..) it needs a closing statement, in this case `}`. This is true for if / else or foreach and so on:

```
<?php if($this){ ?>
some code
<?php } ?>
```

is a valid code, as the code pieces within the php tags are complete statements.

Comment: Victor, thank you for your answer. I think I get what you mean. Just a comment, there are some parts of your answer which I do not understand because grammar or typo, for example: " avoid using the shorthand shorthand is safe as this is unaffected by the setting for newer php versions " could you take a look at it please? thanks again

Comment: @JaumeMal "<?" is a shortopen and not supported on all servers. The proper opening for a php block is "<?php". The close is the both for the same

Comment: @JaumeMal I think you do not understand it because you do not know what the shorthand is: it is the short php opening tag, using "<?" instead of "<?php"

Comment: @VictorRadu no no, I know what the shorthand is, and I know it is suggested not to use it, but you say "avoid using the shorthand shorthand is safe..." which at the moment seems a contradictory statement , and a grammar typo, as there should be some comma or similar. But again, thank you very much for your answer, mine is a comment for clarity of writing.

Comment: @JaumeMal I just noticed I didn't quote the code so it was simply missing a big part of the text :)

Comment: @VictorRadu  aaah! that makes sense now :)

Comment: @VictorRadu , I've added a particular case-scenario to my original question, would you please, review it aswell, for completeness of this Q&A? thank you very much